# How to receive message_payload using https://github.com/farhadi/node-smpp?

Tags: smpp, tlv

We are using [node-smpp](https://github.com/farhadi/node-smpp) and struggling with receiving long (over 160 characters) messages from a SMPP sever. Does anyone have any idea if we should enable some option to get this message payload?

Comment: I don't see anything regarding this. I'd suggest opening an issue and asking about this there.

Comment: Hi, welcome. You are "struggling" — how? Please edit your post to share a [minimal reproducible excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code, and [tell us exactly how it is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then we'll be better equipped to help you.